# How to keep track of svn merges by team mates using mergeinfo

Tags: svn

One of my team members checked out a branch(say A) and merged a revision (say 111) from trunk to to the working copy(branch A) .While merging conflict occurred,so he has to do manually edit the file and commit the changes to A.

I have checked out branch A to my local machine.When i run

cd {branch A}
svn propget svn:mergeinfo

it is not showing revision 111 in its output.However when in run mergeinfo command in my team members working copy revision 111 is showing as merged.

My question is, Does mergeinfo only work in local copy??
HOw can i keep track of what all revisions are merged by my team mates to a branch??

regards

Comment: What if you do `svn up` in the checkout of `{branch A}` and then check the value of `svn:mergeinfo`?  You can also look at that property directly in the repo by passing `svn propget` a branch's URL (you can obtain it by using `svn info`) to verify the property is really there.

Comment: I tried it already.ie, updated my working copy and then run the command svn mergeinfo {url},but the merged revision is not showing.

Comment: ok.got it.I was doing it wrong by trying to commit the merged change from the subtree. I had to commit  the change from the parent directory.

Comment: Well, there *is* an answer, so I suggest you to actually repost your comment as an answer and accept it so it will be easier to read for the next guy.  Also, in the light of what you discovered, how would you rephrase your question? I think we'd better rephrase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.got it.I was doing it wrong by trying to commit the merged change from the subtree. I had to commit the change from the parent directory.